# Maintaining sort while changing random elements

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, sortedcollection

I have come across this problem where I need to efficiently remove the smallest element in a list/array. That would be fairly trivial to solve - a heap would be sufficient.

However, the issue now is that when I remove the smallest element, it would cause changes in other elements in the data structure, which may result in the ordering being changed. An example is this:

I have an array of elements:

```
[1,3,5,7,9,11,12,15,20,33]
```

When I remove "1" from the array "5" and "12" get changed to "4" and "17" respectively.

```
[3,4,7,9,11,17,15,20,33]
```

And hence the ordering is not maintained.

However, the element that is removed will have pointers to all elements that will be changed, but there is not knowing how many elements will be changed and by how much.

So my question is:

What is the best way to store these elements to maximize performance when removing the smallest element from the data structure while maintaining sort? Or should I just leave it unsorted?

My current implementation is just storing them unsorted in a vector, so the time complexity is O(N^2), O(N) for finding the smallest element, and N removals.

Comment: Is there any way to know which elements will be changed or how many or by how much?

Comment: There's not knowing how many elements or how much they will be changed, but the first element will have pointers to those that will be changed. Will put that in the question

Comment: It seems that heap with operation "change priority" is what you need

Comment: One possibility would be to use the heap structure, and once you remove the smallest element, also remove the other elements which were randomly changed and re-insert them into the heap.

Comment: I thought of those, but the problem is that there is no knowing the position of these elements in the heap, so I will have to search through the heap to find the elements to be removed/resorted.

Comment: How about maintaining the element index along with the element value in the heap?

Comment: You are likely looking for a [Self-balancing binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

Comment: @Quorrin: I don't understand your objection to Vaughn's suggestion of a heap -- you apparently already store pointers to the dependent nodes in the first element, so don't you already have the same problem?  (I.e. isn't this a problem regardless of what data structure you're using?)  Pointers to heap locations could get out of date, sure, but so could pointers to array locations.

Comment: What I mean is that I have pointers to the elements themselves, not the locations. Unless you are suggesting that I should maintain pointers to the heap locations as well, and update them as the heap changes, but I am not sure that should be done too.

Comment: Another alternative is a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A.

If you have the list M of all changed elements of the ordered list L,

- go through M, and for every element
- If it is still ordered with its neigbours in M, live it be.
- If it is not in order with neighbours, exclude it from the M.
- Such excluded elements will create a list N
- Order N
- Use some algorithm for merging ordered lists. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm

### B.

If you are sure that new elements are few and not strongly changed, simply use the bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

I would still go with a heap ,backed by an array

In case only a few elements change after each pop,After you perform the pop operation , perform a heapify up/down for any item that reduces in value.  It will still be in the order of O(nlog k) values, where k is the size of your array and n the number of elements that have reduced in size.

If a lot of items change in size , then you can consider this as a case where you have an unsorted array and you just create a heap from the array.